# How to restart RDBMS’s listener in oracle 11g after installing Grid Infrastructure for a Standalone Server

Tags: oracle, grid, listener

I installed Grid Infrastructure for a standalone server and enabled ASM.So it has two ***listener.ora***,one is

***%oracle_base%\product\11.2.0\grid\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora*** and
another is ***%oracle_home%\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora***.

I had defined a *listener_dynamic* in ***%oracle_home%\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora***.
My question is:when i stop RDBMS instance's listener,then restart it,it always says:TNS-01151:Missing listener name in LISTENER.ORA

Here is the output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>set tns_admin=D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
C:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl status listener_dynamic
LSNRCTL for 64-bitWindows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 -Production on 18-OCT-2017 12:30:24
Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=WIN-P269HP3NG00)(PORT=2521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     listener_dynamic
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                18-OCT-2017 11:53:27
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 36 min. 57 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         d:\app\administrator\diag\tnslsnr\WIN-P269HP3NG00\listener_dynamic\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=WIN-P269HP3NG00)(PORT=2521)))
Services Summary...
Service "asset.xcsc.com" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "asset", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "assetXDB.xcsc.com" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "asset", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
C:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl stop listener_dynamic
LSNRCTL for 64-bitWindows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 -Production on 18-OCT-2017 12:31:08
Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=WIN-P269HP3NG00)(PORT=2521)))
The command completed successfully
C:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl start listener_dynamic
LSNRCTL for 64-bitWindows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 -Production on 18-OCT-2017 12:31:26
Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Starting tnslsnr: please wait...
Failed to open service <OracleOraCrs11g_home1TNSListenerlistener_dynamic>, error 1060.
TNSLSNR for 64-bitWindows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 -Production
system parameter file is D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\grid\network\admin\listener.ora
Write to d:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\grid\log\diag\tnslsnr\WIN-P269HP3NG00\listener_dynamic\alert\log.xml log information
TNS-01151:Missing listener name listener_dynamic in LISTENER.ORA
Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

I have specified ***tns_admin***,why each time dose it search listener.ora in grid directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install grid infrastructure you should manage your resources using SRVCTL.
Set your ORACLE_HOME to your grid infrastructure installation then:

```
srvctl start listener listner -l listener_dynamic
```

All your operations should be done through srvctl and not directly. If you didn't register your listener with your grid infrastructure you can do it with:

```
srvctl add listener -l listener_dynamic
```